Rails CanCanCan incorrect behaviour
My code implementation
 def ability
     Ability.new(current_user, current_organization)
 end

inside Ability:
def can_assign_this_responsible(teams_list)
      can :assign_this_responsible, Hr::Employee do |responsible|
          (responsible.not_regular? && teams_list.include?(responsible.hr_team)) ||  owner_of_organization(responsible)
      end
end

Execution:
 def can_assign_responsible
    ability.can?(:assign_this_responsible, @user)
 end

the problem is that even though the condition
(responsible.not_regular? && teams_list.include?(responsible.hr_team)) ||  owner_of_organization(responsible) => false

returns false
the call
 ability.can?(:assign_this_responsible, @user) => true

return true which makes no sense
I am looking for a solution to this problem, why is this happening?
I'm using cancancan 2.0.0
Additional debugging of condition:
(responsible.not_regular? && teams_list.include?(responsible.hr_team)) ||  owner_of_organization(responsible)

responsible.not_regular? => false
teams_list.include?(responsible.hr_team) => true
owner_of_organization(responsible) => false
